# Prime number curiosity : $ \lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{\exp(1+\sum_{i=1}^n\frac1{p_i-1})}{\prod_{i=1}^n(1+\frac1{p_i-1})}=\frac{79}{25}$ !?

Tags: limits, number-theory, prime-numbers, asymptotics, fractions

Let $0<n$ be a positive integer.
Let $p_n$ be the $n$-th odd prime.

$$p_1 = 3,p_2=5,p_3=7,p_4=11,\ldots$$

Let

$$f(n) = \exp \left(1 + \sum_{i=1}^{n}\frac{1}{p_i-1} \right)$$

Let

$$g(n) = \prod_{i=1}^{n} \left(1+\frac{1}{p_i-1} \right)$$

Let

$$t(n) = \frac{f(n)}{g(n)}$$

Then this limit exists

$$ \lim_{n \to +\infty} t(n) = \frac{79}{25}$$

And for sufficiently large $n$ we have :

$$ \frac{79}{25} - \frac{\ln(n)+2}{n^2-1} < t(n) < \frac{79}{25} - \frac{1}{n^5}$$

How to formally prove it ?

Comment: If we take the first $306$ odd primes ( up to $2017$ ) we get $3.159951...$, already pretty close to $79/25 = 3.16$

Comment: Note that the denominator is the Euler product so we can write $g(n)=\frac{1}{2}\zeta(1)$ and using the primorial, we have that $g(n)=\exp\left(-\sum_{i=1}^n \ln\left(\frac{p_i-1}{p_i}\right)\right)$ so you want to show that $\sum_{i=1}^\infty \left[\frac{1}{p_i-1}+\ln\left(\frac{p_i-1}{p_i}\right)\right]=\ln\left(\frac{79}{25}\right)-1.$ Perhaps this is how you started and I just worked backwards so it might not be very useful.

Comment: What’s the source of this problem? I would’ve naively expected this to be irrational. If you derived 79/25 numerically, then maybe it’s just a coincidence.

Comment: @MandelBroccoli When you write $g(n) = \frac12\zeta(1)$, I assume you made a typo, but I'm not sure what you intended.  (perhaps it even doesn't matter and we should just skip that part of the comment, but that's where I stopped)

Comment: @BrianMoehring sorry, I meant $g(n)\to \frac{1}{2}\zeta(1)$ as $n\to \infty$ by the Euler product. Actually that's probably notational abuse since $\zeta(1)$ doesn't converge or anything. The important part is that we can write $g(n)=\frac{1}{2}\frac{p_n\#}{(p_n-1)\#}$ where $(\cdot)\#$ is the primorial function. The way I wrote it was simply me being lazy because $\zeta(1) = \lim_{n\to \infty} \frac{p_n\#}{(p_n-1)\#}.$

Comment: Why do you state something false as if it is true? You could ask *whether* it is true and perhaps why you think so. But to state it as true when it is not, big fat -1.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is of extremely low quality. Its very premise is an unsupported and false claim. It also shows no effort.

Comment: @Servaes “Extremely low quality” is a bit harsh, compared to other questions we see at this site. I do agree that it should have been phrased as an open question, or evidence of the conjecture have been provided

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set $p_0=2$ so that $1+\sum_{i=1}^n=\sum_{i=0}^n$ and $\prod_{i=1}^n=\frac12\prod_{i=0}^n$. Then the limit is $2e^S$, where $$S=\sum_p\left[\frac1{p-1}+\log\left(1-\frac1p\right)\right]$$ (and the sum is over *all* primes). This [can be computed very precisely](https://oeis.org/A221712/a221712.pdf), using $$S=\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\varphi(n)}n\log\zeta(n)$$ with [Euler's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function) $\varphi$ and [Riemann's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riemann_zeta_function) $\zeta$, or even more efficiently, using $$S=\sum_{p\leqslant L}\left[\frac1{p-1}+\log\left(1-\frac1p\right)\right]+\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{\varphi(n)}n\log\zeta_{p>L}(n)$$ with $\zeta_{p>L}(s)=\zeta(s)\prod_{p\leqslant L}(1-p^{-s})$, and $L$ moderately large.

Under [PARI/GP](https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/), running `2*exp(experiment(20))` (or so) after

```
sumprime(L,f)={my(r=0);forprime(p=2,L,r+=f(p));return(r)};
experiment(L)=sumprime(L,p->1/(p-1)+log1p(-1/p))+suminf(n=2,\
 (log(zeta(n))+sumprime(L,p->log1p(-p^(-n))))*eulerphi(n)/n);
```

gives $\small 2e^S=\color{red}{3.16}004224934664893010400401922739912991300144543962144985264596958636415\dots$

Note also that $S=M-\gamma+\sum_p\frac1{p(p-1)}$, where $\gamma$ is the well-known [Euler–Mascheroni constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_constant), $M$ is the less-well-known [Meissel–Mertens constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meissel%E2%80%93Mertens_constant), and the last sum found, say, [here](https://oeis.org/A136141) on OEIS.

Comment: How many digits are certain ? What code did you use ?

Comment: Quite clever. I wasn't able to get over the hump after the expression for $S$ but wasn't aware of this method of estimation for $\sum_p \frac{1}{p(p-1)}.$

Comment: @mick: All the digits are. (Added the code.)

Answer (score 7):

This is false.

In particular, I numerically (with $30$ digits of precision) computed the product.  After $555$ odd primes (prime $4021$), the total exceeds $79/25$. Since this is a strictly increasing sequence, this means that the limit is greater than $79/25$.

Running it for the first $10000$ odd primes up to $104743$ gives that this converges to $3.16004…$.

Comment: I will have to check that myself. Thanks for the effort. What do you think it converges too ? How about $\sqrt 10 = 3.162277..$ ? I have Sage, but im terrible at it. Maybe some code ...

Comment: From the rate of convergence, the error should be $<1/n$, so I’m pretty sure that those first 5 digits are correct (so not $\sqrt(10)$). I highly doubt it’s rational, though I wouldn’t be surprised if it were some weird combo of functions/values.

Comment: how did you get that rate of convergence or error ?

Comment: The log is $\sum 1/(p_i -1) + log((p_i-1)/p_i)$. Taylor expanding both terms has the $1/p_i$ terms cancel leaving a $1/(2p_i^2)$ and higher border terms. That is upper bounded by $1/n^2$ and integrating that gives $1/n$

Comment: yeah that makes sense +1